# Android: Animate marker movement

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I am fetching the current location of my vehicle using KSOAP2 and showing it on the map. Till now I was clearing all markers (`mGoogleMap.clear();`) and then adding a new marker for each new location update (`mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(buslatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));`)

However this approach causes the marker to move suddenly and it does not look so good. So I stored the old LatLang in a variable and want the marker to move slowly from the old to new location and zoom/adjust the map so that the new location comes at the center. Code used:

```
                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                busMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(buslatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));

                                double[] startValues = LastbuslatLng==null ?  new double[]{buslatLng.latitude, buslatLng.longitude} : new double[]{LastbuslatLng.latitude, LastbuslatLng.longitude};
                                double[] endValues = new double[]{buslatLng.latitude, buslatLng.longitude};
                                ValueAnimator latLngAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new DoubleArrayEvaluator(), startValues, endValues);
                                latLngAnimator.setDuration(600);
                                latLngAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                                latLngAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                                        double[] animatedValue = (double[]) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                                        busMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(animatedValue[0], animatedValue[1]));
                                    }
                                });
                                latLngAnimator.start();
                            }
                        });
LastbuslatLng = buslatLng;
```

I would have to take care of the case when at start there will be a single location. However, I dont see the marker moving and also it does not zoom. Can anyone please help me on where am I wrong ?

Comment: Do you just want to animate your camera into specific location?

Comment: what I want is that when I receive a new GPS coordinate, the marker should "smoothly" move from the old to new position, instead of an abrupt jump and after, the camera should bring the new position marker in the center of the map.

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate camera into specific location, I use the following snippet, In the following example camera will be smoothly moved to this `37.4219999,-122.0862462`  location

```
 CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(new LatLng(37.4219999,-122.0862462))
            .zoom(16)
            .bearing(0)
            .tilt(45)
            .build();

mGooglemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);
```